# How can I boot the dhcp server for my internal network board?

Tags: dhcp

I configured the dhcp server and now I want it to boot for the internal network board. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First, find out what the DHCP service unit is called, if you don't know (we can't tell from your question):

`systemctl list-unit-files | grep dhcp`

This might yield something like `dhcp3.service`. Then do:

`sudo systemctl start dhcp3.service`

replacing `dhcp3.service` by whatever the first command told you.